# my console.log() shows up twice in my chrome console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I put a `console.log()` in my render method in my class base `Component` my `console.log()` shows up twice in my *chrome* console, but I haven't this issue in my *firefox* console

[image: my chrome console]

My Component :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts } from "../actions";

export class PostList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.posts);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Post List</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  posts: state.posts,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(PostList);
```

Comment: can you show your codes?

Comment: @JeeMok Yes of course , I edited it

Comment: are you sure `PostList` didn't get rendered twice?

Comment: @JeeMok Yes, i found the answer this is because of <React.StrictMode> tag that wrap my application

Comment: I see, that's great! 

Comment: That was it! Thank you @UniQue!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely because react now wraps your application in `<React.StrictMode>`, [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) combined with the browser having react dev tools will starts calling components multiple times for debugging purposes. This won't happen in a production build.